# UILabel number of rows with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a view I use in my application in many places, sometimes inside tableView and sometimes in a regular view.

Here is my view:

[image]

The main label the one left to the Heart image is limited to 3 lines, I want to know if there is a 4th line so I can show a "Read More" button.

I saw many solution here in stackoverflow but none of them is good enough mainly because most of them use preferredWidth which use a fixed number, however I don't really know what is the width of the label because in iPhone 6 the width of the label will be different from iPhone 5.

As you know I can't use the label frame because with auto layout the frame is calculated on runtime.

Someone know about a good solution? and please don't give me answer like use "ViewDidLayoutSubviews" in the VC.

I'm not presenting any code because in terms of autolayout everything work perfect.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? - Show some "Read more" button if a label contains more than 3 lines? Without any code, but pure auto layout?

Comment: NO, no, how can I show button and hide button without code!?
I just want a way to do it with auto layout and something that doesn't involve any hardcoded value like in most answers.

Comment: You probably don't. At least not in a clean way. Why not use some code?

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, of course I mean in code, it's not possible not to use code for this.
I'm not a beginner, there is not a one single xib or sb in my projects, all I want is the piece of code or a way to do it.

Comment: Then we are back to square one - what have you tried so far? Why *not* use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? That is the probably the correct place to go.

Comment: because if I use it in UITableView there is no way to use viewDidLayoutSubviews, and mainly because it's not a clean way to do it.

Comment: Firstly: it is **THE** perfectly fine way - you want to change the layout of your view based on the layout of other components. Okay, if it is in a cell: subclass the cell and override the corresponding UIView method.